# Adaptive card id collision when using same card for second time

Tags: c#, botframework, chatbot, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

I have a dialog (bot framework dialog) which works great the first time user enters it. Dialog displays user with an adaptive card containing Input.ChoiceSet which has a id property set to "substitution". When user enters the same dialog for the second time ChoiseSet gets displayed properly but on Action.Submit I get an id collision for id "substitution".

My issue is similar to issue of this user: https://github.com/microsoft/AdaptiveCards/issues/3225#issuecomment-710626684. But his solution to the problem has no effect for my case. I keep getting the same error.

I get that id should be unique but I shouldn't be forced to dynamically set id of the same ChoiceSet card.

My adaptive card:

```json
{
  "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
  "type": "AdaptiveCard",
  "version": "1.3",
  "body": [
    {
      "type": "TextBlock",
      "text": "<to-be-set-with-code>"
    },
    {
      "type": "Input.ChoiceSet",
      "id": "substitution",
      "style": "compact",
      "isMultiSelect": false,
      "value": "1",
      "choices": []
    }
  ],
  "actions": [
    {
      "type": "Action.Submit",
      "title": "OK",
      "data": {
        "msteams": {
          "type": "messageBack",
          "text": "back"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

My code (inside dialog step):

```cs
private async Task<DialogTurnResult> SubstitutionStepAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var adaptiveCardJson = await File.ReadAllTextAsync(Cards.TextWithChoiceSetCard, cancellationToken);

    var card = AdaptiveCard.FromJson(adaptiveCardJson).Card;

    var textBlock = card.Body[0] as AdaptiveTextBlock;
    textBlock.Text = "Who will be your substitution?";

    // get current teams user info
    var userStateAccessors = UserState.CreateProperty<UserProfile>(nameof(UserProfile));
    var userProfile = await userStateAccessors.GetAsync(stepContext.Context, () => new UserProfile(), cancellationToken);

    // generate choices
    var adaptiveChoices = new List<AdaptiveChoice>();
    foreach (var user in ApiWrapper.RetrieveInstanceUsers())
    {
        // do not include current user and bot user
        if (user.UserName == ClientData.Username || string.Equals(user.Email, userProfile.UserPrincipalName, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)) continue;
        adaptiveChoices.Add(new AdaptiveChoice
        {
            Title = $"{user.UserName} ({user.Email})",
            Value = user.ToJson()
        });
    }

    var choiceSet = card.Body[1] as AdaptiveChoiceSetInput;
    choiceSet.Choices = adaptiveChoices;
    
    var attachment = new Attachment
    {
        ContentType = "application/vnd.microsoft.card.adaptive",
        Content = card
    };
    var reply = stepContext.Context.Activity.CreateReply();
    reply.Attachments = new List<Attachment> {attachment};

    return await stepContext.PromptAsync(nameof(TextPrompt), new PromptOptions {Prompt = reply}, cancellationToken);
}
```

Comment: We tried to repro the issue and we are also getting the id collision error.

Comment: @Prasad-MSFT thanks for looking into it. So I'm guessing this is a bug? Any idea where to go from here on? Is this a bug with AdaptiveCards nuget?

Comment: @Prasad-MSFT any follow up? Is there an issue I can track about this?

Comment: We have raised a bug for this issue and engineering team is looking into it. We will inform you once we get any update. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for update, keep me posted please.

Comment: @Prasad-MSFT I have the same problem. News about this bug?

Comment: @SteeBono, Engineering Team is analysing this issue. We will get back to you once we get any update. Thanks!

Comment: @Prasad-MSFT hello, is there any news yet? I have a project where I need this in 2 weeks time. Or is there any known workaround?

Comment: @SteeBono did you find a workaround for your issue?

Comment: @MaticCavalleri I found a workaround

Comment: @Prasad-MSFT any follow up?

Comment: Engineering Team is analyzing this issue. We will get back to you once we get any update. Thanks!

Comment: I have the same problem and have been unable to solve it for hours. I was following this [tutorial](https://binarygrounds.com/2021/06/12/adaptive-cards-in-bot-dialog.html) and it still didn't work... but then I changed this line: `Content = card` for this one: `Content = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(card.ToJson())` and it worked, the exception disappeared and I don't need to generate GUID.

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround to fix the exception:
*AdaptiveCards: Collision detected for id 'cardFieldId'*.

Let's say we have these WaterfallSteps:

- InitialStepAsync
- CardStepAsync
- FinalStepAsync

And let's say that we have this card:

```
{
    "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
    "type": "AdaptiveCard",
    "version": "1.3",
    "body": 
    [
        {
            "type": "ColumnSet",
            "columns": [
              {
                "type": "Column",
                "width": 2,
                "items": [
                  {
                    "type": "TextBlock",
                    "wrap": true,
                    "text": "Select an assistance."
                  },
                  {
                    "type": "Input.ChoiceSet",
                    "choices": [],
                    "placeholder": "---",
                    "id": "assistanceId"
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "ColumnSet",
            "columns": [
              {
                "type": "Column",
                "width": "stretch",
                "items": [
                  {
                    "type": "ActionSet",
                    "actions": [
                      {
                        "type": "Action.Submit",
                        "title": "CANCEL",
                        "id": "bnCancel"
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "type": "Column",
                "width": "stretch",
                "items": [
                  {
                    "type": "ActionSet",
                    "actions": [
                      {
                        "type": "Action.Submit",
                        "title": "CONFIRM",
                        "style": "positive",
                        "id": "bnConfirm"
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

The source code of steps:

```
private async Task<DialogTurnResult> InizialStepAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var message = "Insert YES or NO.";
    var promptMessage = MessageFactory.Text(message, message, InputHints.ExpectingInput);
    return await stepContext.PromptAsync(nameof(TextPrompt), new PromptOptions { Prompt = promptMessage }, cancellationToken);
}

private async Task<DialogTurnResult> CardStepAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var actionTypes = (List<ActionTypeFullItem>)stepContext.Options;

    var txt = (string)stepContext.Result;
    if (txt.Equals("YES", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    {
        // If user say 'YES', show card.

        // Retrieve JSON of our card from EmbeddedResource
        var jCard = await Utils.GetCardJsonAsync("assistanceType");

        // Workaround BUG: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69358336/adaptive-card-id-collision-when-using-same-card-for-second-time
        // Replace 'FIELDID' with 'FIELDID_RANDOMGUID'.

        var chooseFieldId = $"assistanceId_{Guid.NewGuid()}";
        var bnCancelFieldId = $"bnCancel_{Guid.NewGuid()}";
        var bnConfirmFieldId = $"bnConfirm_{Guid.NewGuid()}";

        jCard = jCard.Replace("assistanceId", chooseFieldId);
        jCard = jCard.Replace("bnCancel", bnCancelFieldId);
        jCard = jCard.Replace("bnConfirm", bnConfirmFieldId);

        // Create the Adaptive Card from JSON
        var card = AdaptiveCard.FromJson(jCard).Card;

        // Popolate our choose field (extensions method created by me)
        var chooses = new List<AdaptiveChoice>();
        foreach (var actionType in actionTypes)
        {
            chooses.Add(new AdaptiveChoice
            {
                Title = actionType.Title,
                Value = actionType.Id.ToString()
            });
        }
        card.SetChoiseField(chooseFieldId, chooses);

        // Popolate cancel button submit data (extensions method created by me)
        // We need 'assistanceFieldId' to retrieve the value of choose filed in the next step.
        card.AddSubmitData(bnCancelFieldId, new Dictionary<string, object>
        {
            { "confirm", false },
            { "assistanceFieldId", chooseFieldId }
        });

        // Popolate confirm button submit data (extensions method created by me)
        // We need 'assistanceFieldId' to retrieve the value of choose filed in the next step.
        card.AddSubmitData(bnConfirmFieldId, new Dictionary<string, object>
        {
            { "confirm", true },
            { "assistanceFieldId", chooseFieldId }
        });

        // Prompt card
        return await stepContext.PromptCardAsync(card, cancellationToken);
    }

    return await stepContext.NextAsync(new { confirm = false }, cancellationToken);
}

private async Task<DialogTurnResult> FinalStepAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var actionTypes = (List<ActionTypeFullItem>)stepContext.Options;

    var selectedActionType = default(ActionTypeFullItem);

    // Example JSON result
    // { "confirm":true, "assistanceFieldId": "assistanceId_d68fbc77-d96e-4d1c-b3eb-4d4c31ccf2af", "assistanceId_d68fbc77-d96e-4d1c-b3eb-4d4c31ccf2af":"19" }

    var jObject = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse((string)stepContext.Result);
    if (jObject.ContainsKey("confirm") && !(bool)jObject["confirm"])
    {
        // User has clicked the 'cancel' button -> go back to the first step.
        return await stepContext.ReplaceDialogAsync(InitialDialogId, actionTypes, cancellationToken);
    }

    var assistanceFieldId = (string)jObject["assistanceFieldId"];
    if (selectedActionType == null)
    {
        selectedActionType = actionTypes.SingleOrDefault(a => a.Id.ToString().Equals((string)jObject[assistanceFieldId], StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
    }

    return await stepContext.EndDialogAsync(selectedActionType, cancellationToken);
}
```

The idea is very simple, instead of always keeping the same ID for each field, we add a random guid to always have a different ID.

Comment: Seems like it works, thanks. Looks like only "Input.ChoiceSet" id has to be unique each time for it to work. I made it a bit simpler with class variable that is saving up the Guid so you know what the Guid is in next step (no need to pass this data to json response that way). It's a bit cleaner this way I think. Thanks again for taking the time to post your workaround. Hopefully Microsoft still comes through with a proper fix soon.

Comment: @MaticCavalleri I don't save the Guid as a global variable in the class because I don't know if the Dialogs are thread safe. So I had decided to pass the value as json parameter. I hope too.

Comment: I believe they are as various BotStates are also present in them (so they have to be else users could become mixed up if two users use the same dialog at same time). I believe this is taken care of because inside DI container you usually inject IBot as transient. I might be wrong however.